I am trying to install with install4j installer but get OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM error
I am trying to install a software (Solibri Office version 24.9.0.38) using install4j installer but get error:
Standard error output from the process: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000603800000, 536870912, 0) failed; error='The paging file is too small for this operation to complete' (DOS error/errno=1455)
I have read tens of similar error messages from internet but all of them point to page file size which I do not believe is the problem here.
The computer has 32Gb memory and I changed the Page file size already from System Managed to static 16Gg and booted. Nothing changed. The same error message.
Is there anything else besides the pagefile that could cause the error?

This question might be off topic but check a solution here

Seems to be a problem with your Windows pagefile configuration. It says it in the error message. You didn't share any specific reasons why you don't believe it is the cause. A system configuration issue is off topic in [so]. https://superuser.com/ seems to be a more appropriate site. Or read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/how-to-determine-the-appropriate-page-file-size-for-64-bit-versions-of-windows
